# Django Questions: Custom User and iOS

Tags: python, ios, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I am newbie in Django so i'm a bit confused with some of it's features. I have to do a project for my university. It consists of a desktop-web app where employees can do stuff like handle files, record files and upload files on a MySQL database. In addition, there's an iOS native app (written in Objective-C) where users can register themselves, log in, and ask for the data that employees have saved early.

First of all:  Is it possible to build a server app that communicates with an iOS app (sending-recieve data, notifications) using Django-frameworks (and i suppose also Django-Rest-Framework)? If yes, are there any tutorials/guide/book to better understand how this communication work and how i can really do this?

My second question is related to custumizing users on Django.
For my project, i need two classes of user:

- Employee (with registration_id as primary key): this user can only log in on desktop-app
- Driver : this user can only log in on ios-app

Can i have multiple users like here:

```
class Employees(AbstractBaseUser):
registration_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=10,unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    #etc etc etc

class Driver(AbstractBaseUser):
       license_plate =....
       first_name = ....
       #etc etc etc
```

is that reasonable?

Sorry for my bad English.

I will appeciate any kind of help

Thank you

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP communication also known as RESTful communication is the universal language of the web and is ideal because it can work between operating systems and back end frameworks such as Django and iOS etc.. etc..

You will have quite a bit of research you need to do.  Django is written in Python, so assuming you know some Python, Django should not be too difficult to pickup, but you should definitely start with it's poll app tutorial.

Django-Rest-Framework is probably the best tool to build a restful web API for your Django project.  Your iOS app will make http calls (GET, POST, PUT) etc... to your Django API.  There is really no better documentation than Django-Rest-Framework's website to learn how to use it.

Ultimately there is no book that will tell you step by step how to do this.  You have to learn several different areas and put the pieces together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've already tried the poll app tutorial, but it doesn't explain much the custum user subject . I will try also the django-rest-framework tutorial.  Thank for the hint